# Is it possible to configure Sonicwall TZ350 to provide DNS for DHCP clients?

Tags: dns, dhcp-server, sonicwall

I've got a SonicWall TZ350, and I've set it up to provide DHCP to a local LAN (192.168.168.X).
Right now, when a DHCP client on the local lan does nslookup of another client, it fails because the name server that the SonicWall is providing is the name server passed through from the WAN.

Is there a way to get the SonicWall to ack as a DNS server for the DHCP clients? I would like the SonicWall to offer itself as DNS server, and answer for any DHCP clients, but forward anything else to the WAN DNS server (similar to how it works in pfSense when you use the DNS Forwarder option with 'Register DHCP Leases in DNS Forwarder).

Is this simply not a thing that the SonicWALL does? I certainly can implement my own DNS server/DHCP server on the LAN (pfSense), but it seems like a natural thing for the SonicWall to do, so I tend to think I just don't know what I'm doing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, SonicWall does not act as a real DNS server. If you have a tiny network, you could enable DNS Proxy on the SonicWall and fill out the cache by hand for your local domain. Anything more than that and you'll have to setup a local DNS server.

Comment: So SonicWall can act as a DHCP server but NOT as a DNS Server? Strange
How would I resolve the name of a station which got an IP from DHCP ?

Comment: @Klaus - The DHCP response includes the IP of the DNS server.

Comment: the IP of an external DNS Server or the IP of the SonicWall box acting as DNS Server ??

Comment: @Klaus The IP address of the DNS servers you have entered into the Sonicwall DHCP configuration. You can select 'inherit' to use the DNS servers configured under your network settings. Chosing manual lets you fill out the DNS servers of your choice.

Comment: @Silbee : but this still does not answer the question: will the SonicWall work as a DNS server itself without any external DNS server and resolve the host names in the local network, which has got an IP address from SonicWalls DHCP ?

Comment: That question was already answered. No, sonicwall doesnt do DNS. That includes devices registered via its DHCP service, because *sonicwall doesnt do DNS*. Sonicwall describes your specific question here https://www.sonicwall.com/support/knowledge-base/configure-the-appliance-to-resolve-internal-domain-names-and-ips/170505917055646/ As you can see, they rely on an external DNS service.